# Why is Person and Breadcrumb data not showing?

Tags: seo, microdata, schema.org

On most pages of my site I make use of Microdata. Some things such as the data blog post was created, and review ratings show up in search results. Other information such as Person and Breadcrumb data doesn't.

### Person

On my homepage I have a the following code. Pasting it into the [Google Structured Data Testing Tool](http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/richsnippets) shows "Abergavenny Wales - Web Developer", but pasting the URL in doesn't show this, any idea why?

```
<div id="banner" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Person">
  <h1>Working <a href="/freelance-web-developer" title="Freelance Web Design & Development">Web Solutions</a></h1>
  <h2>
    <a href="/services/freelance-ruby-on-rails-development-cardiff-abergavenny-wales-uk" title="Freelance Ruby on Rails Web Developer">Ruby on Rails</a>, <a href="/services/freelance-sinatra-ruby-development-cardiff-abergavenny-wales-uk" title="Freelance Sinatra Web Developer">Sinatra</a> &amp; <a href="/services/freelance-drupal-developer-designer-cardiff-abergavenny-wales-uk">Drupal</a> Development by <br class="responsive" /> 
    <a href="http://www.netmagazine.com/features/net-awards-2011-top-10-developers" title=".net Awards 2011: top 10 developers" rel="nofollow">Award Nominated</a> <a href="/freelance-web-developer"><span itemprop="jobtitle">Web Developer</span></a><br class="responsive" /> 
    <span itemprop="address" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/PostalAddress">Based in <a href="/services/abergavenny-uk-web-design-development" title="Web Designer & Developer in Abergavenny"><span itemprop="addressLocality">Abergavenny</span></a>, <span itemprop="addressRegion">Wales</span>, <span itemprop="addressCountry">UK</span></span>.
  </h2>
</div>
```

### Breadcrumb

The same is also apparent with breadcrumbs. The following code works when pasted into the [Google Structured Data Testing Tool](http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/richsnippets) but the URL doesn't return the breadcrumb.

```
<ol id="breadcrumb">
  <li itemscope itemtype="http://data-vocabulary.org/Breadcrumb">
    <a href="/services" itemprop="url">
      <span itemprop="title">Services</span>
    </a> &#8250;
  </li>  
  <li itemscope itemtype="http://data-vocabulary.org/Breadcrumb">
    <a href="/services/freelance-ruby-on-rails-development-cardiff-abergavenny-wales-uk" itemprop="url">
      <span itemprop="title">Ruby on Rails Development</span>
    </a>
  </li>
</ol>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe because Google can't show everything in the preview, and it seems that your Google+ profile takes precedence over other metadata.

Comment: G+ Profiles and breadcrumbs work together fine. I don't think person creates rich snippets yet.

Answer (score 0):

I've not tested any Person functionality of schema.org yet. But I've had a nice conversation with a [person](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2325248/ajax) that could explain me, [why breadcrumbs are not working with schema.org](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17796286/2386943) yet. May that answer is matching for Person too.

Additionaly:
Also this helper can help you create valid microdata: http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/richsnippets