# schema.org Breadcrumb Navigation is not working

Tags: schema.org

I want to have a breadcrumb navigation on my website which is also shown as breadcrumb navigation in the google search results.

That's no problem, just working with microdata as seen here:
https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/185417?hl=en

And checking if it works with:
http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/richsnippets

so everything works fine right now, but now I noticed that data-vocabulary.org which is used in the google microdata example is outdated and schema.org is the new standard.

And there comes the problem, this schema.org isn't working.

I used a [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10282750/2386943) in 
Google Webmaster Tools Richsnippets and linter.structured-data.org. Google Richsnippets doesn't understand it and Linter prints:

```
Errors

ArgumentError: invalid byte sequence in US-ASCII

Structured data

The data did not match any templates on file. Submit a request to the mailing list to request support for additional templates.

No formats detected.
Parser statistics
RDF::Microdata::Reader: 8 statements
Matched Templates:  none
```

So that whole schema.org is very confusing and seems not to work.

Someone ones what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For now you should not use Schema.org for breadcrumbs. Just stay with data-vocabulary.org although it is outdated for other types. There were several similar discussions here already. Check [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13088284/breadcrumb-with-schema-org) where John Mueller from Google says that schema.org is not supported for breadcrumbs rich snippets.

> at the moment we don't support the current schema.org breadcrumb
>   markup for rich snippets, so you'd need to use one of the other
>   documented formats. w3.org/2011/webschema/track/issues/10 also has
>   some details about the difference. – John Mueller Jan 30 at 14:59

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But it's not really statisfying me, cause it's quite the same answer then [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13088284/breadcrumb-with-schema-org), which is from November 2012. So is it correct to say schema.org was a attempt of some search engines to collect there structured data, which overall failed? (cause primary things like breadcrumbs aren't working) And everyone should optimize for the search engine she/he thinks it's the best?

Comment: Not really. Schema.org is supported by all major search engines and is actively developed by them. You may check this open mail list (http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/public-vocabs/), it lives and sounds. And as schema.org WG participant I can say that a lot of hot discussions occur internally. The problem is that some of the types and use cases (e.g. breadcrumbs) are not covered yet with attention they deserve. But I hope this will be fixed some day. But of course some nuances in markup consuming will always vary at different Search Engines.

Comment: hi ajax, cause of your last comment the current answer to my question is: Use schema.org where you can use it, otherwise use a equivalent and check later on for a schema.org markup. Thanks for your help, I have accpeted your first answer belonging to your comment. If someone reads that in the future and knows a schema.org way to use breadcrumbs, I would be very thankfull to here it.